# How to use Selenium to get the housing data

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm trying to get the data from the webpage http://www.har.com/4311-Childress-St/sale_40763013. It has the house address, price and other info. I'm trying to get all the data but only successfully retrieved the address, city and zip. Below is my code. How do I get the other info, like the county, stories etc.?

```
def getHarData(driver):
driver.get("http://www.har.com/4311-Childress-St/sale_40763013")
try:
    address = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "heading_22")))
    cityzip = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "sub_heading")))
    #price = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "heading_22 pb15"))) 
    print (address.text + ", " + cityzip.text+ ", " +price.text)
except TimeoutException:
    print("data not found")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only some of the specific fields, I would make a nice *reusable* function to get a field value by the field name/label:

```
def get_field_value(driver, field):
    field = field.capitalize() + ":"
    return driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'dc_label' and . = '%s']/following-sibling::div[@class = 'dc_value']" % field).text
```

Usage:

```
county = get_field_value(driver, "county")
print(county)  # prints "Harris County"
```

Complete working sample:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


def get_field_value(driver, field):
    field = field.capitalize() + ":"
    return driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'dc_label' and . = '%s']/following-sibling::div[@class = 'dc_value']" % field).text

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.har.com/4311-Childress-St/sale_40763013")

# wait for the page to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "dc_title")))

county = get_field_value(driver, "county")
print(county)
```

Comment: You are awesome! It works like magic. Could you please introduce me a good tutorial for the xpath? I just don't know how to write a good/complex xpath like you.

Comment: @teapot there is plenty of information available online, but I would just say, practice, practice, practice! :)